# PHP sessions don't expire. Ever

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm transferring my application to another server, but I have some issues with the PHP sessions that don't seem to expire.

In php.ini I've set:

```
session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor = 1
session.gc_maxlifetime = 300
```

Cookies are enabled, of course. And still, after 5 minutes, if I refresh the page I'm still logged in. Even if I close the browser and reopen the page. **Edit**: actually, it seems that closing the browser *does* clear the session.

Since *every* request passes through a certain script first (`RewriteRule / begin.php`), I'm quite lucky and I could get over the problem with this:

```
session_start();
if (time() > @$_SESSION['sessionLimit']) {
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
}
$_SESSION['sessionLimit'] = time() + ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
```

But still, I don't get what I'm doing wrong and why in the old server everything was fine (even if `session.gc_divisor` was set to 10).

Old server: Windows Server 2003, Apache 2.4, PHP 5.4.5, all 32 bit

New server: Windows Server 2008 R2, Apache 2.4, PHP 5.5.4, all 64 bit

Comment: `auto_prepend_file` is a better way to have a "startup" script than .htaccess rewrites.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Nice. But I'm not using .htaccess, that's in the Apache's conf file. And anyway, begin.php is used for *every* request, including images and so on.

Comment: What’s your session.save_path set to, and what kind of OS is this running on?

Comment: @CBroe It has no value, but that's the same for the old server. The OS is Windows Server 2008 R2, as stated in the question.

Comment: Ar you the _only one_ using that server/domain? What if you visit it in another browser after 5 minutes + a bit, and then refresh the page where you're logged in? (And watch out for ajax polling et al., those will update your sessions timestamp). Examine your access logs for this.

Comment: @Wrikken I'm the only one that uses that server. No AJAX is involved in the page I open. Your test doesn't change the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this answer: [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes#answer-1270960)

Gumbo explains the matter better than I ever could.

In particular, Gumbo explains why `session.gc_maxlifetime` is not reliable and he recommends implementing session timeout yourself, using a simple time stamp that denotes the time of the last activity (i.e. request), and updating that timestamp with every request:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

Comment: Ah, that was informative, I ended up in that answer a while ago. In the end that's exactly what I did, as stated in the question. Since it still has no marked answer, I might as well mark yours for pointing to the correct explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that configuration is fine. Check permissions on the directory where your sessions files are stored. Maybe some permission restrictions do not allow PHP to delete them - in such case sessions will not get garbage collected. Also check the modification dates, if the files are really older than the maxlifetime.

Comment: That would be `c:\windows\temp`. You mean that PHP may be able to create a session file, but not to erase it? Wouldn't `session_destroy` also fail?

Comment: Hmm, if it is temp, then it is rather not the case with permissions. I am not sure about session_destroy, as it actually destroys session data (documentation says: "Destroys all data registered to a session"). It does not destroy session identifier, so it is possible that session file is not removed, but only cleared of session data.

And what about file dates?